# Is there any way to get AKS namespaces?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-sdk

As of now, we can deploy any container with the namespace. I want to get all the namespace list form the AKS cluster. I have referred the following links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks

Comment: What about now? Do you solve the problem or any more questions?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afriad you cannot find the REST API to get AKS namespaces in Azure REST API which used to manage the Azure resources. But the namespaces are the conponent of the Kubernetes. Just use the command `kubectl get namespace` to get all the AKS namespaces.